# Python: CTypes memory leak with Structure

Tags: python, memory-leaks, ctypes

Does Python `ctypes` have a known memory leak?  I am working on a Python script having code like the below snippet, using `ctypes`, that for some reason is causing a memory leak.  The "`while True`" in this example is to test for the leak caused by calling the function.  It is being run on Windows with Python 2.5.4:

```
import ctypes
def hi():
    class c1(ctypes.Structure):
            _fields_=[('f1',ctypes.c_uint8)]
    class c2(ctypes.Structure):
            _fields_=[('g1',c1*2)]

while True:
    test=hi()
```

The leak can be tested using ProcessExplorer -- as it keeps looping, Python keeps taking up more and more memory.  It seems to require having two Structure subclasses where one of the classes has a "multiple" of the other one (using the `*` operator), but I'm not sure if the condition is more basic than that.  Even if `del test` is added in the loop, it still leaks memory.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Edit: Because someone suggested it might not have garbage-collected yet, here is an edited version that does garbage-collect but still appears to leak memory:

```
import gc
import ctypes
def hi():
    class c1(ctypes.Structure):
            _fields_=[('f1',ctypes.c_uint8)]
    class c2(ctypes.Structure):
            _fields_=[('g1',c1*2)]

while True:
    test=hi()
    test2=gc.collect()
```

Comment: How much does it leak? It it one byte for each `c1` created? Have a counter that's printed every 50,000 calls to `hi()` or so so you know.

Comment: In ProcessExplorer, the "Working Set" memory steadily increases by about 20-30 KB every second, and every so often the "Private Bytes" catches up to that.  After about 12 minutes I'm already over 59 MB of memory and counting for the second snippet running in an interpreter.  How do I put a counter within the code that tells you how much memory is being taken up?  Can anyone else corroborate me on this?

Comment: The easiest way would be to add `from itertools import count` at the top then change `while True:` to `for c in count():` and then add `if not c % 50000: print c` in the loop. Then, if the `print`s are too frequent or too infrequent to be useful, increase or decrease that `50000`.

Comment: I've added a bug-tracker case; here is the cross-reference: http://bugs.python.org/issue12998

Comment: As you can see from the replies to that case, it's not a leak. You really should not attempt to use process explorer as a leak detection tool.

Comment: @David it most certainly __is__ a leak in the `ctypes` implementation, just not a case they care about. It also seems it doesn't happen with 2.6+, and since 2.5 is basically in "source only / security fix only" update mode, this isn't going to be fixed.

Comment: @agf it's by design for performance grounds. That's not a leak in my book.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a memory leak, that just means the garbage collector hasn't run yet. And even if the garbage collector does run, odds are good that there's some kind of memory pooling going on.

ProcessExplorer isn't a good debugging tool, especially for memory.

Comment: Even if I add "import gc" at the beginning and "test2=gc.collect()" inside the loop, the memory it takes up still keeps growing.  What do you mean by "memory pooling"?  Shouldn't the memory get freed at some point?

Comment: A memory pool means that an area is set aside (within python) which holds free memory. It's an optimization technique. It only *looks* like the memory is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The script in and by itself doesn't leak.  Running with `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)` shows that the created structure types are collectable, and `gc.garbage` remains empty in every loop iterations, so there are not uncollectable objects.  Running the script with `time` on a Linux system doesn't show an steady increase in memory consumption, too.